# SignalR 'long polling' sends multiple requests simultaneously

Tags: signalr, long-polling

I have written a simple 'analytics' tracking tool for my site, which has boolean columns such as

`Visited_Store`
`Visited_Homepage`
`Checkout_Started`
`MainVideo_Played` 
`MainVideo_Completed`

I am also using Google Analytics but wanted a secondary place to montor activity.

---

I had been testing my application primarily in Chrome which of course will use  web sockets by default. I switched to long polling because I wanted to be able to monitor the requests in Fiddler.

The way the hub works is pretty simple. The SignalR client sends events which sets flags (columns) when a particular event has completed. So on invocation it does the following :

- Find row for user - or create if non existent
- Set flags
- Save row

I had no concurrency issues until I switched to long polling - when I found instant deadlocks.

My client will often send multiple events simultaneously (separate issue to fix - yes) and when using web sockets they are nicely queued and executed one by one. So obviously any deadlocks are going to be extremely unlikely.

Long polling is a different story - I suddenly found that my hub method was being entered multiple times and trying to create multiple rows, and deadlocks and 'row modified' errors all over the place.

One simple solution is just to `lock(lockObj)` when making a request, but if I have many clients I'd rather not do that. Another is to catch the deadlock and re-execute the request which right now occurs on just about every page load.

Is there perhaps a way to configure SignalR long polling to **not** send requests all at once? Or some other way to execute requests in turn (like ASP.NET does when you use SessionState).

Comment: Sounds like the deeper issue is that your database layer does not tolerate concurrent access, perhaps you want to focus on that first.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but what happens for the first request (where no database row exists for the session) is that two in memory rows are created at exactly the same time and then inserted. The database detects either a primary key violation or a deadlock but that just seems to be using up resources uncessarily. I'm not sure what else could be done in the db. Even an atomic create of an empty row would only partially solve it for the first event